# Generates Assets only for production symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I am using symfony2 for my application I am making my all js and css files in one file using the following code

```
{% block stylesheets %}
        {% stylesheets
            'updated/lib/bootstrap-datepicker/css/datepicker3.css'
            'updated/lib/prism/prism_default.css'
            'updated/lib/select2/select2.css'
            'updated/css/style.css'
            output='css/complete-registration.css'
            filter='cssrewrite'
            filter='yui_css'
    %}
    {% endstylesheets %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/complete-registration.css') }}" />
```

It works fine for me but problem is during my development whenever i change any thing on my js and css file I have to generate assets again which takes too much time so anyone can suggest me any thing.

what I do that i dont have to generate assets in my development environment ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
{% if app.environment == 'dev' %}
    <!-- your styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="..." />
{% else %}
    {% stylesheets
        'updated/lib/bootstrap-datepicker/css/datepicker3.css'
        'updated/lib/prism/prism_default.css'
        'updated/lib/select2/select2.css'
        'updated/css/style.css'
        output='css/complete-registration.css'
        filter='cssrewrite'
        filter='yui_css'
    %}
    {% endstylesheets %}
{% endif %}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/complete-registration.css') }}" />
```

Comment: It will increase the line of code. Do you think that's the only way ?

Comment: few months ago? yes, because I've similar problem, but I think nothing changed for today. You can still wait for another answers

Answer (score 0):

Read doc: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#dumping-asset-files-in-the-dev-environment

and then set

```
# app/config/config_dev.yml
assetic:
    use_controller: false
```

and this prevents you from dumping files every change you made:

```
$ php app/console assetic:dump --watch
```